# Laravel validation of an JSON/array of integers is not working

Tags: laravel, api, validation

I'm trying to validate a JSON object (specifically an array of integers) that I send via an API request but it doesn't validate successfully.

The body of the request has a variable of the form:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| id | [1,2, "hello"] |

The validation I do is as follows:

```
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'id' => 'bail|required|json',
    'id.*' => 'bail|integer|exists:products,id',
]);
if($validation->fails()){
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'fail',
        'message'=> $validation->messages()->first()
    ],422);
}
```

But nevertheless it is passing validation.
Apparently the validation of "id.*" is not processing it but I don't understand why.

Can someone please help me?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: why are you sending it as a json text ? if you still need it like that, you need to do a custom validation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures

Comment: It seems the `id.*` validation pattern is used to validate an array of object/associative_arrays.

Comment: @N69S I really don't need to send it as a JSON object. I just need to send it as an array but if I validate it as an array, the validation rule is not passing. It's returns a message saying "The id must be an array". That's why I validate it as a JSON object. Is something wrong with this?

Comment: it's not a "json object", it's just a string representing a json object. there is nuance. Add to your question how you are sending this data.

Answer (score 0):

please add '.' like below
'id.*.' => 'bail|integer|exists:products,id',

Comment: Thanks for commenting but it is not working. It still passes validation.